# Get values from User and update into mysql database in Springboot Controller

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Banking system Project Where User Should be able to create an account in any available branch. Branch Creation will be maintained by admin. I had two tables(Entities) like **BranchDetails** and **AccountDetails**.
[image: db_Structure]
The `BranchId` Column is the primary key in **BranchDetails** and Foreign key in **AccountDetails**. Now When user Creates an account, he will input the Preferred **Branch name** and the **AccountHolder** name. I had to Insert this Account in **AccountDetails** Table which matching the branchId which the user had entered.

How do i achive this. So far i have tried,

**BranchDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "branchdetails")
public class BranchDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int branchId;
    @Column( name = "branchName")
    private String branchName;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "branchdetails")
    private AccountDetails accountDetails;

/getters and setters
}
```

**AccountDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accountdetails")
public class AccountDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int customerId;
    @Column(name = "customerName")
    private String customerName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "branchId")
    private BranchDetails branchdetails;

/getters and setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class ApiController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/branchcreation", method = RequestMethod.POST
          ,consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
  @ResponseBody
  public String brCreation( BranchDetails br, String branchname){
      br.setBranchName(branchname);
      branchrepository.save(br);
      return "Sucesspage";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/accountcreation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String AcCreation(AccountDetails ad,BranchDetails br, String branchname,String customername){
    br.setBranchName(branchname);
    ad.setCustomerName(customername);
    accountrepository.save(ad);
    return "Sucesspage";
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? These are different DBMS products. Remove the irrelevant tag from your question.

Comment: I'm using MySql. Tags removed ):-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare `AcCreation` method to receive branch id (the branches already exist, so you could send their ids and names to your frontend form's `select` component) and customer name (provided by the user in the `input` field):

It would look like this (I changed the name to `createAccount`, because it sounds naturally, there is no need to use shortcuts in method's name, but in the end it's your choice):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/account-creation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String createAccount(String customerName, Integer branchId){
    accountRepository.createAccount(customerName, branchId);
    return "Sucesspage";
  }
```

Look at the removed code from the service method.

Details connected with creation on the database should be contained by database access layer, in this case the class `AccountRepository` and database layer methods should be called by service's methods - in your case we left out the service class).

So you would create Account instance inside its method and then set the `branchId` field.

Or you could do something like this (you would have to have two separate repositories, one for AccountDetails, second for BranchDetails entities):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/account-creation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String createAccount(String customerName, Integer branchId){
    BranchDetails branchDetails = branchRepository.find(branchId);
    AccountDetails accountDetails = new AccountDetails();
    accountDetails.setCustomerName(customerName);
    accountDetails.setBranchDetails(branchDetails);
    accountRepository.save(accountDetails);
    return "Sucesspage";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.. Actually i do have separate repositories for both entities.
But in the last block of code, where is that **setBranchDetails** comes from. I don't have such field or setters in Accountdetails

Comment: It's the setter, which you could generate (eg. by using Lombok library) or write by yourself. The key is to have the ```branchDetails``` instance and then just set it - like the regular field - on the entity. ```save``` method should do the job and create the new user entry in the database.

Comment: Okay so what Parameter should the **setBranchDetails** setter accept ? Should I Pass the BranchDetails entity in the parameter?

Comment: Yep, just like that - Spring will automatically use the ```branchId``` field and set it in the ```AccountDetails``` table.